# problem loading several OBJ files in ThreeJS and setting their positions

Tags: javascript, position, loading

I want to load a number of OBJ files and position them at specific positions for a mechanical assembly. I can do a number of snippets like

```
{
  const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
  objLoader.load('obj/'+'AA2.obj', function(object) { 
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
       if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
          child.material.color.setRGB (0.6,0.3,0.3); 
   });
  object.position.x=-1065.4;
  object.position.y=700.0;
  object.position.z=-937.1;
  scene.add( object );
  })
}
```

and this works fine.

But I want to do that in a loop. I am using the array:

```
const parts = [
  ['AA1',-1065.4,0.0,-937.1,0.6,0.3,0.3],
  ['AA2',-1065.4,700.0,-937.1,0.6,0.3,0.3],
  ['AB1',-225.0,0.0,-937.1,0.6,0.3,0.3],
  ['AB2',225.0,0.0,-937.1,0.6,0.3,0.3],
  ...
  ];
```

and then I loop with:

```
for (var i = 0;i < parts.length; i++) {
    const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load('obj/'+parts[i][0]+'.obj', function(object) {
      object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
          child.material.color.setRGB (parts[i][4], parts[i][5], parts[i][6]);
        });
      object.position.x=parts[i][1];
      object.position.y=parts[i][2];
      object.position.z=parts[i][3];
      scene.add( object );
    })         
  }
```

and this fails in that all objects have the same final color, and they are all set at 
position 0.

There are no error messages in the console. What am I doing wrong? Does this have
something to do with asynchronous loading?

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while calling the callback function, the loop has already completed its work and set the last value for `i`. That is why you always see the same color. Below is a similar example. As one solution, just replace the `var` with `let`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('var: ', i), 100)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('let: ', i), 100)
}
```